# Batching Results from ReactiveX Observable

Tags: python, reactivex, rx-py

Say I have an observable that looks like this (this is Python, but should be general to all languages):

`rx.Observable.from_iterable([[1],[],[2],[3],[],[],[4],[5,6],[7],[8,9],[10]])`

I want to ultimately be able to batch the Integers into lists of length 5 and be able to pass those to a function, so something like this:

```
batch_function([1,2,3,4,5])
batch_function([6,7,8,9,10])
```

In reality, the incoming data will be an inifinite stream of (potentially empty) lists. I just want to make sure that my subsequent calls to `batch_function` are not made until I've accumulated 5 actual values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need a stream of 5-element lists at the end? Would it suffice to subscribe an observer to the stream and manually buffer in the observer, calling `batch_function` whenever the buffer exceeds 5 elements?

Comment: @concat I just posted what's worked for me using `buffer_with_count`. I need the list because it's more efficient to send batches to the downstream function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet is working for me using `buffer_with_count`. I'm not sure if there's a more parsimonious way to do it, though, i.e., without the `flat_map`.

```
BUFFER_COUNT=5
rx.Observable.from_iterable(iter(get_items())) \
  .flat_map(lambda it: it) \
  .buffer_with_count(BUFFER_COUNT) \
  .map(lambda my_array: do_something_with(my_array)) \
  .subscribe(lambda it: print(it))
```